# Do not get output for shell script using if and for

Tags: bash, shell

I do not get any printed result for that, but I don't understand why?

```
read -e -i "no" -p "Install? " result

if [ '$result' == 'yes' ]; then
  declare -a subs=('one' 'two')
  for sub in "${subs[@]}"
  do
    echo "$sub"
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to double quote `$result` rather than single quote, otherwise it won't expand.

`[ '$result' == 'yes' ]` will never evaluate to true because it is trying to compare the literal `$result` to the literal `yes`.

Additionally, as Kusalananda points out; the `==` operator is for bash test constructs `[[` while the `=` operator is for standard (POSIX) test constructs `[`.

Therefore, you should change that line to: `[ "$result" = 'yes' ]`

---

Another good tool to know about is the `set` builtin and its `-x` switch which can be used to trace your scripts.  If you add `set -x` to the top of your original script and run it you will see the following printed out:

```
+ read -e -i no -p 'Install? ' result
Install? yes
+ '[' '$result' == yes ']'
```

As you can see, it is trying to compare '$result' to 'yes'.  When quoted correctly, you wouldn't see the variable `$result` but rather it's expansion like so:

```
+ read -e -i no -p 'Install? ' result
Install? yes
+ '[' yes == yes ']'
+ subs=('one' 'two')
+ declare -a subs
+ for sub in '"${subs[@]}"'
+ echo one
one
+ for sub in '"${subs[@]}"'
+ echo two
two
```

Whenever you are banging your head against the wall with a script you should turn on `set -x` and trace what it's doing and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Also, `=` within `[ ... ]`, `==` within `[[ ... ]]`. `[[ ... ]]` is `bash` extended syntax. `[ ... ]` is standard `test` syntax (which uses `=` for string comparisons).

Comment: @Kusalananda, anyway, `-p`, `-e`, `-i`, `declare` are all bashisms as well. `[[ ... ]]` comes from `ksh`. All shells that support that `[[...]]`  (including `bash`) also support `==` as an alternative to `=` in their builtin `[` command. I'd still stick to `=` as opposed to `==` though. There's no assigment in `[[...]]` or `[` so no need to disambiguate == vs =.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Jesse_b's answer.

### Why do I need to double quote the variable?

The difference between single and double quotes:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between
>   single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of
>   all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
>   when history expansion is enabled, !.

From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

You need to remember this well, it will save you the trouble of debugging for a while.

Comment: If you're *ever* writing 500 lines of shell script, it's almost 100% certain that you're using the wrong tool for the job, or that you need to learn shell scripting better.  (The typical 200-line production shell script that I see condenses to about 30 lines when the correct utilities are used, e.g. `find` instead of some monstrous `ls | xargs stat | variable assignment | complicated logic | something else` pipeline.)